# If $F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed, then $F\setminus\operatorname{int}(F)$ is nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

A set $E \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is *nowhere dense* if for every interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R},$ there exists a subinterval $J\subseteq I$ such that $J \subseteq E^c.$

An *interior* of $F$ is the largest open subset of $F.$

> **Question:** If $F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed, then $F\setminus\operatorname{int}(F)$ is nowhere dense.

My attempt:
Fix an interval $I.$ 
Take $J = \operatorname{int}(F) \cap I\subseteq I.$
Clearly 
$$J\subseteq (F\setminus \operatorname{int}(F))^c = F^c \cup \operatorname{int}(F).$$

Is my proof correct? This seems too simple.

Comment: It does not seem clear why $J$ is an interval.

Comment: Note that $J$ is open, show that $J$ contains an interval.

Comment: Presumably in the definition we need a *non-empty* subinterval $J$. Your approach will automatically yield $J=\emptyset$ if $\operatorname{int}(F)$ is empty. But, you still need to produce a $J$!!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your answer does not quite work. To see this, take $F=\{0\} $. Your proof does work in the case where $\operatorname{int}(F)\neq \emptyset $ though.

Take $I $ to be an open interval. One way to do this problem is to note that if $I $ is such that $I\cap (F\setminus \operatorname{int}(F))\neq \emptyset  $, then $I $ must contain a point in $F^c $. To see this recall that by the definition of an interior point $F\setminus \operatorname{int}(F)$ contains only points which given a ball with any radius that ball must intersect $F^c $. Furthermore since $I $ is open there exists a ball around each element contained in $I $, so $I\cap F^c\neq \emptyset$.

Now, since $F $ is closed, $F^c $ is open, and hence $F^c\cap I $ is open.